# SSIS Connection to ORACLE (Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have an **"Native OLE DB\Oracle Provider for OLEDB"**  connection in SSIS package to execute a procedure on ORACLE.

Procedure is working fine but in log file I am seeing below mentioned warning, which is slowing down the execution.

```
Warning : Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
```

The procedure is having **5 inputs** and **2 out paras**. After reading few articles which point says it could be due to data type/size mismatch.

I personally think its something to do with connection setting. I created a simple task of deleting data from a table without any para or variable. Still there was a warning

Its simple delete statement.

```
BEGIN DELETE FROM KC.KC_PAYMENT; END;
```

The warning appears after "validation is completed". and before the delete statement "Progress" event.

Deepak

Comment: I am having the same issue. I dont have any parameters to my sproc but I still get errors. This doesnt seem to be a data type issue.

Comment: Can you use an OLE source to a rowcount? Does preview data show anything.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to work around this problem. What I am thinking as of now is

1) Store the Connection string that points to oracle into sql server table or in variable.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/

2) Check for security while fetching the records.

3) Use the "Oracle provider for OLE DB" from SSIS, don't use the "Microsoft Provider for Oracle" because a 64 bit version of it does not exist.

4) Schedule your packages with the SQLAgent.

Comment: I have tried all the options that you listed. But none of them seem to work. I am working in VS 2008 environment and have all the permissions to execute and connect to Oracle.

Comment: Did you try changing your project to 32 bits?

Comment: I cannot award the bounty right away. 23 hours to go.